# Is there a way to keep history of states with aasm gem?

Tags: ruby, aasm

I am wondering if this gem provides a way to keep history of states. I probably can do this by adding a callback to each event but I am wondering what other people think about this approach.

Comment: I am not sure about aasm gem but i have used with state machine. https://github.com/wvanbergen/state_machine-audit_trail this might be helpful.

Comment: AASM does not support it and there are currently no plans for it.

Comment: In general, you need to consider that you will create an ever growing table when you start saving state changes... this can lead to huge, hard to migrate tables, and ultimately to id-space exhaustion. A no-SQL store, like DynamoDB, might be a choice here.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at this recently and the two solutions I found were [the assm_history gem](https://github.com/gogiel/aasm_history) and [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). Given that I already had paper_trail installed, I ended up going with that.

edit: Per @BKSpurgeon's question below, we ended up adding an `after_save` callback on the model, and then created a new row in a new table on every state transition. Prior to that, I added a transition from `:any => :any` and did it there.

```
  after_save -> { record_item_transition }, if: :state_changed?
```

Comment: would you be able to share your implementation details?

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Papertrail! Its major flaw is that it stores the diffs for all models in your project in just one table, creates a huge ever-growing table, and its YAML format is hard to query.